# I tried to get the URL from a youtube video and play it with mediaplayer but it immediately ends

Tags: android

I want to play the audio from a youtube video in a separate service by selecting it with a web view, but when i click on play it skips to the setOnCompletionListener part

I've already tried setting the Data source to an Uri instead of the Url filepath but it still didn't work

Class for playing music in a service

```
package com.example.music_player;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static android.content.Intent.getIntent;
import static java.lang.String.valueOf;

public class MusicPlayer extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    int i=0;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

    }

    int length = 0;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        int k=Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("position"));
        final ArrayList<String> songs = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("songs");
        String url;
//k's from -1 to 3 are for other settings to play songs from internal storage (skipping songs, pausing audio, etc)
        if (k==1) {}

        if (k==-1) {}

        if (k==0) {}

        if (k==2) {}


        if (k==3) {}

        if (k==4) {

            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            url=intent.getStringExtra("url");
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                i++;
                String test="test";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),test,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (i==songs.size()) {

                    i=0;

                }

                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songs.get(i));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Class for showing a web view and getting the URL of the video when the button is pressed

```
package com.example.music_player;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Youtube_Source extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView youtube;
    Button play;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube__source);
        youtube=findViewById(R.id.youtube);
        youtube.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
        youtube.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings settings=youtube.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
//getting the list of songs from the internal memory from MainActivity
        final ArrayList <String> songs=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("songs");

        //Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(songs.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        play=findViewById(R.id.button7);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent(Youtube_Source.this,MusicPlayer.class);
                i.putExtra("url",youtube.getUrl());
                i.putExtra("position",String.valueOf(4));
                i.putStringArrayListExtra("songs",songs);
                String url=youtube.getUrl();
                //Toast.makeText(Youtube_Source.this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startService(i);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (youtube.canGoBack()) {

            youtube.goBack();

        }

        else {

            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok so I managed to solve my problem which was caused by setting the datasource to a wrong url address.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Youtube Player Android SDK (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/). That would be easier.

In your layout xml, add this:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In your main activity,

```
public class SampleActivty extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
```

Do initialization in `OnCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_play);

  YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = 
            (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);

  youTubePlayerView.initialize("YOUR API KEY",
    new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
          youTubePlayer.loadVideo("5xVh-7ywKpE");

          // If you wish to only load the video but not play, use `cueVideo()` instead of using `loadVideo()`.
          //youTubePlayer.cueVideo("5xVh-7ywKpE");
      }
      @Override
      public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {}
      });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what i'm trying to do is something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261652/how-to-get-the-youtube-download-link-using-java

Comment: @GreenFlash I know this way cause I used that before. I think the most difficult part of this method is that you will need to parse every video URL and its header first to get the related information of video content. So, I changed to use Youtube SDK directly, That would be much easier.